# Real vector space with hermitian structure

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $V$ a **real** vector space, endowed with an **hermitian** form.

To set things more formally, let $(e_1, \dotsc, e_n)$ a basis of $V$, 
then the data of the hermitian form is encoded in an Hermitian matrix
$S=(s_{i,j})$, defining by linearity a form:
$$
\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{i,j} s_{i,j} x_i y_j 
$$
where $x = \sum_i x_ie_i$ and $y = \sum_i y_ie_i$ generic elements of $V$.
Then $V\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ can be trivially viewed as an hermitian vector space through the form defined by $S$. But I'm interested only in the real vector space $V$ and not its complexification.

Is there a known theory for the study of such spaces?

Comment: Do you ask for the structure of a **real** subspace of for example $\mathbb C^n$ by considering it as a real space?

Comment: I guess you can turn it like that since $V$ is naturally embedded in its complexification seen as a real vector space. Notice nonetheless that although the norms of elents of $V$ are reals, its is not the case for the scalar product that can be arbitrary complex numbers.

Comment: I don’t understand what do you want to do with the hermitian form? It won’t become symmetric bilinear in a natural way.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there are known properties for such real subspaces with regards to the Hermitian product. I don't want it to become a Euclidean space at any moment.